# Why is Pygame so much slower than 2d game engines?

Tags: python, pygame, godot

I am a godot user and a Python user. In pygame, in a simple game like pong, I had an average of 55-60 FPS in fullscreen. In addition, when ported to Kivy, I had an average FPS of 60-70FPS. But when I coded this in Godot, and got an average FPS of 180-200 in the viewport, while profiling! My program was extremely similar in both, and I wasn't static typing at all in Godot. Why is pygame so slow and is there anyway I can make it faster?

Comment: My guess would be that it's the engine internals that are much more efficient.

Comment: Pygame uses SDL for the graphics, maybe that is less efficient that the inbuilt 2D graphics engine of Godot or maybe Python has more overhead than Godot Script. It also might be that your program was an outlier and other attempts would show different results. Just because one try showed that pygame was slower in this example doesn't mean it always is.

Comment: i havnt used Godot, but it looks like Godot uses faster languages like c# and c++, python is really slow compared to other languages

Comment: Godot's main language is GDScript - a dynamically typed language with similar syntax to python.

Comment: @Trilarion I have tried other things and Godot is always around 80FPS faster, I just don't have any statistics on those tests.

Comment: Maybe it would be good to include a short description of the other things that have been tried in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Godot is using [OpenGL ES for drawing to the window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godot_%28game_engine%29#Rendering).  PyGame is based on SDL, which does not use *hardware graphics* primitives at all.  You could also port your game to [Kivy](https://kivy.org/), which supports OpenGL ES too.

In terms of pushing pixels to the screen, graphics being drawn with a **C**PU Vs running on **G**PU is not a contest the CPU can ever win.  That said, for a whole lot of game styles, PyGame is fast enough.  There is absolutely no point updating the screen faster than the monitor is refreshing.

I would expect a basic [Pong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pong) in PyGame to always run at full-FPS.  On a huge high-DPI display, maybe even erasing the background is enough of a pixel-load to drop the FPS.

Comment: I actually did make this game in Kivy - you can see it on my Github account, But it still got around 60-70FPS. Since Kivy uses PSdl2 by default, I thought that it was also using SDL and was therefore similar. I also for some reason wrote 30, I meant 55. I have updated it.

Comment: It seems that [SDL might also use OpenG](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/guidevideoopengl.html). Maybe the pygame developers just didn't select it. I wonder if the [SDL2 based versions of pygame](https://github.com/renpy/pygame_sdl2) are faster.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution That SDL 1.x page is talking about support for using PyGame and PyOpenGL together. You still have to use PyOpenGL's API for your graphics. If you want something faster, you need to see if PyGame has anything built on SDL2's Render API. (It's designed to provide GPU-accelerated 2D acceleration for tasks like porting DirectDraw games to modern systems. Ryan Gordon described the Render API as "the most hyped up Super Nintendo you've ever seen" in one of his talks.)